# Is there a "know-it-all" or "versatile" badge?

Tags: feature-request, badges

Is there a badge that is earned when you successfully answer questions from a wide range of topics (i.e. tags)? If not, should there be one?

Comment: [Here's your know-it-all badge](http://i.stack.imgur.com/So4sk.png); I earned mine a long time ago.

Answer (score 11):

The [Generalist](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/15/generalist) badge is awarded to users with an answer score of at least 15 for each of any 20 of the top 40 [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags). As the top 40 tags cover pretty much 90% of what most software development encompasses these days, you should be covered.

I think I quite prefer the name "Versatile" to "Generalist", though :)

Comment: I do not, makes me think of... you know...

Comment: @animuson: I don't get it :/

Comment: [Urban Dictionary's definition.](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=versatile)

Comment: @animuson: Ouch. Now I'm wondering how many people upvoted just for the double entendre.

Comment: At least 1, now.

Comment: @jadarnel27: Dammit.

Comment: I was going to link to the Wikipedia page for it, but they had a somewhat inappropriate picture on there...

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is. It's the [Generalist badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/15/generalist).

> Provided non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [Generalist](http://tackoverflow.com/badges/15/generalist) badge for having a score over 15 in 20 of the top 40 tags for the site, so long as the site in question has at least 40 tags with 200 questions